# How to remove file from "recently opened" list using keyboard in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I see only clicking 'X' way. Is there a key to do that? `Del`, `backspace` not working.[image]

Comment: You need to clear all recently opened list??

Comment: @DhruvilPatel no, selected

Answer (score 0):

I think your only option once the file is highlighted in the QuickOpen view that you want to remove from the list is to hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice (that seems to focus the `Open to the Side` icon next to the `X` close, then hit the <kbd>RightArrow</kbd> to focus the close `X`, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  I don't think there is any dedicated way to do it otherwise.

Comment: "_I don't think there is any dedicated way to do it otherwise._" - to somewhat substantiate: searching "file recent" in keyboard shortcut editor only shows `workbench.action.openRecent`, `workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNextInRecentFilesPicker`, `workbench.action.quickOpenNavigatePreviousInRecentFilesPicker`, and `workbench.action.clearRecentFiles`